# Use Fortran subroutine in R? Error: Return type mismatch

Tags: r, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to learn how to use fortran code inside R. I was able to follow [this tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/fortran-and-r-speed-things-up/). Now, I'm trying to use that as a base plus [this fortran program to calculate pi](https://www.pdc.kth.se/education/tutorials/summer-school/mpi-exercises/mpi-lab-codes/pi_serial.f90/view). I create a file Fpi.f90 with this code:

```
subroutine pi(avepi, DARTS, ROUNDS)
double precision, intent(out)   ::  avepi
integer, intent(in)             ::  DARTS, ROUNDS
integer                         ::  MASTER, rank, i, n
integer, allocatable            ::  seed(:)
double precision                ::  pi_est, homepi, pirecv, pisum

! we set it to zero in the sequential run
rank = 0
! initialize the random number generator
! we make sure the seed is different for each task
call random_seed()
call random_seed(size = n)
allocate(seed(n))
seed = 12 + rank*11
call random_seed(put=seed(1:n))
deallocate(seed)

avepi = 0
do i = 0, ROUNDS-1
  pi_est = dboard(DARTS)
  ! calculate the average value of pi over all iterations
  avepi = ((avepi*i) + pi_est)/(i + 1)
end do
end subroutine pi


double precision function dboard(darts)
integer, intent(in)           :: darts
double precision              :: x_coord, y_coord
integer                       :: score, n

score = 0
do n = 1, darts
  call random_number(x_coord)
  call random_number(y_coord)

  if ((x_coord**2 + y_coord**2) <= 1.0d0) then
  score = score + 1
  end if
end do
dboard = 4.0d0*score/darts

end function
```

When

```
$ R CMD SHLIB ./Fortran/Fpi.f90
gfortran  -fpic -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong  -c  Fortran/Fpi.f90 -o Fortran/Fpi.o
Fortran/Fpi.f90:22.15:

pi_est = dboard(DARTS)
               1
Error: Return type mismatch of function 'dboard' at (1) (REAL(4)/REAL(8))
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:161: recipe for target 'Fortran/Fpi.o' failed
make: *** [Fortran/Fpi.o] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

After adding `double precision ::  dboard` to `pi` I get a different error.

```
R CMD SHLIB ./Fortran/Fpi.f90
gfortran -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -o Fortran/Fpi.so ./Fortran/Fpi.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: ./Fortran/Fpi.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
./Fortran/Fpi.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'Fortran/Fpi.so' failed
make: *** [Fortran/Fpi.so] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use `implicit none`. That is very bad! Due to implicit typing `dboard` is thought to he default real inside `pi`.

Declare it as double precision, or if possible with R, use modules. An interface block can also be used to declare `dboard` inside `pi`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if R supports fortran modules, I'm trying to get something a bit more complicated than the f77 tutorial to work and failing :( After declaring dboard inside pi I get a different error

Comment: I created a follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395435/use-fortran-subroutine-in-r-undefined-symbol . Your answer took me one step in the right direction, thanks!