# Use Fortran subroutine in R? Undefined symbol

Tags: r, fortran

This is a follow up [to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394755/use-fortran-subroutine-in-r-error-return-type-mismatch). I wrapped my Fortran code in a module and now it compiles when I run:

```
R CMD SHLIB ./Fortran/Fpi.f90
```

This is my Fortran code:

```
Module Fpi 
IMPLICIT NONE
contains 
    subroutine pi(avepi, DARTS, ROUNDS)
    double precision, intent(out)   ::  avepi
    integer, intent(in)             ::  DARTS, ROUNDS
    integer                         ::  MASTER, rank, i, n
    integer, allocatable            ::  seed(:)
    double precision                ::  pi_est, homepi, pirecv, pisum, dboard

    ! we set it to zero in the sequential run
    rank = 0
    ! initialize the random number generator
    ! we make sure the seed is different for each task
    call random_seed()
    call random_seed(size = n)
    allocate(seed(n))
    seed = 12 + rank*11
    call random_seed(put=seed(1:n))
    deallocate(seed)

    avepi = 0
    do i = 0, ROUNDS-1
      pi_est = dboard(DARTS)
      ! calculate the average value of pi over all iterations
      avepi = ((avepi*i) + pi_est)/(i + 1)
    end do
    end subroutine pi


    double precision function dboard(darts)
    integer, intent(in)           :: darts
    double precision              :: x_coord, y_coord
    integer                       :: score, n

    score = 0
    do n = 1, darts
      call random_number(x_coord)
      call random_number(y_coord)

      if ((x_coord**2 + y_coord**2) <= 1.0d0) then
      score = score + 1
      end if
    end do
    dboard = 4.0d0*score/darts

    end function


end module Fpi
```

I'm trying to run this in R:

```
mypi <- function(DARTS, ROUNDS) {
  dyn.load("./Fortran/Fpi.so")
  retvals <- .Fortran("pi", DARTS = as.integer(DARTS) , ROUNDS = as.integer(ROUNDS), avepi = as.numeric(1))
  return(retvals$avepi)
}

mypi(DARTS = 50000, ROUNDS = 10)
```

and I get this error:

```
Error in dyn.load("./Fortran/Fpi.so") : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/ignacio/local/projects/PI/./Fortran/Fpi.so':
  /home/ignacio/local/projects/PI/./Fortran/Fpi.so: undefined symbol: dboard_
```

Comment: Try `function dboard(darts) bind(C, name="dboard_")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes down to the declaration of `dboard`:

```
   double precision                ::  pi_est, homepi, pirecv, pisum, dboard
```

Here you are saying that `dboard` is an *external* function, rather than a module procedure.  This explains why there is a symbol `dboard_` coming into play. You want to remove that:

```
double precision                ::  pi_est, homepi, pirecv, pisum
```

and instead rely, in `pi` on the module procedure-ness of `dboard`: `pi` already knows about it without this declaration.

Now, beyond that, because `pi` is in a module there is going to be some name mangling going on for that subroutine itself.  I'd solve this problem by making `pi` itself a (C) interoperable procedure.

```
Module Fpi 
  IMPLICIT NONE
contains 
  subroutine pi(avepi, DARTS, ROUNDS) bind(C)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_double, c_int
    real(c_double), intent(out)   ::  avepi
    integer(c_int), intent(in)    ::  DARTS, ROUNDS
    ...
```

and then using `.C` rather than `.Fortran`.

You can keep `pi` and `dboard` in the module, and this latter needn't even be interoperable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix the name of the fortran call inside the R function. You typed "pi" where it should be "Fpi". Also, why not bring the function to your path instead of passing a long path inside the function?

```
mypi <- function(DARTS, ROUNDS) {
  dyn.load("./Fortran/Fpi.so")
  retvals <- .Fortran("Fpi", DARTS = as.integer(DARTS) , ROUNDS = as.integer(ROUNDS), answer = as.numeric(1))
  return(retvals$answer)
}
```

mypi(DARTS = 50000, ROUNDS = 10)

Comment: the fortran module `Fpi` has a subroutine `pi` and a function `dboard`, that is why I have `.Fortran("pi"...` I'm not briging the function  to my path because I don't know how to do it :(. I know how to program in R and in Fortran, but I have only a few hours of experience trying to use Fortran inside R. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You may know this  manual then:  http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Calling-C-from-FORTRAN-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 1):

Aparently I cannot wrap the subroutines in a module. This fortran code is working:

```
subroutine dboard(darts, dartsscore)
  implicit none
  integer, intent(in)           :: darts
  double precision, intent(out) :: dartsscore
  double precision              :: x_coord, y_coord
  integer                       :: score, n

score = 0
do n = 1, darts
  call random_number(x_coord)
  call random_number(y_coord)

  if ((x_coord**2 + y_coord**2) <= 1.0d0) then
  score = score + 1
  end if
end do

dartsscore = 4.0d0*score/darts

end subroutine dboard

subroutine pi(avepi, DARTS, ROUNDS)
  implicit none
  double precision, intent(out)   ::  avepi
  integer, intent(in)             ::  DARTS, ROUNDS
  integer                         ::  MASTER, rank, i, n
  integer, allocatable            ::  seed(:)
  double precision                ::  pi_est, homepi, pirecv, pisum

interface 
   subroutine dboard(darts, dartsscore)
      implicit none
      integer, intent(in)           :: darts
      double precision, intent(out) :: dartsscore
   end subroutine dboard
end interface

! we set it to zero in the sequential run
rank = 0
! initialize the random number generator
! we make sure the seed is different for each task
call random_seed()
call random_seed(size = n)
allocate(seed(n))
seed = 12 + rank*11
call random_seed(put=seed(1:n))
deallocate(seed)

avepi = 0
do i = 0, ROUNDS-1
  call dboard(darts, pi_est)
  ! calculate the average value of pi over all iterations
  avepi = ((avepi*i) + pi_est)/(i + 1)
end do
end subroutine pi
```

and this is the R code:

```
system("R CMD SHLIB ./Fortran/Fpi.f90")

mypi <- function(DARTS, ROUNDS) {
  dyn.load("./Fortran/Fpi.so")
  retvals <- .Fortran("pi", avepi = as.numeric(1), DARTS =  as.integer(DARTS), ROUNDS =  as.integer(ROUNDS))
  return(retvals$avepi)
}

mypi(DARTS = 50000, ROUNDS = 10)
```

Comment: You're trying to learn so I'll remind you to use implicit none - you had after your module declaration in the question which is perfect. But this answer should have implicit none after each subroutine declaration.

Comment: Thanks @Ross I just added `implicit none`. Any other suggestion to improve my answer will be greatly appreciated